# How to make sure the overflow css property is hidden in the kendo grid when an iframe is loaded before the container div is shown on IE10?

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-grid, internet-explorer-10

I have a set of tabs that load the content inside iframes. When I select one of the tabs which its frame was loaded before making the container div show I get the following behavior occurs in IE10:

Images:

[image: Screen shot of kendo demo issue inside iframe]

I was able to reproduce the issue using the following code:

Html:

```
<div style="display: none;">
        <iframe src="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index" frameborder="0" style="height:1000px; width:100%; z-index: -1;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
                    $("div").css('display', 'block');
            }, 2500);
}
```